# Split pot on a straight or 6th high card kicker?

Tags: texas-hold-em, hand

So tonight my fiancé had a 9,10. And my brother in law had 9,K. On the board it was 6,7,8,10,J. So I know that you can only use 5 cards total. And I was thinking split pot. Was I right or wrong because my brother in law said that he had K high. But that would’ve been his 6th card so his K didn’t matter. Was I wrong or right to split the pot?

Comment: you were right, it is a split pot. both players have 789TJ as their hand.